# While Setting up Fluent Bit as a DaemonSet to send logs to CloudWatch Logs getting error as Failed to pull image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, fluent-bit

I need to send my cluster logs to Cloudwatch using FluentBit
I have setup the fluentbit Daemon but while running the command

```
kubectl get pods -n amazon-cloudwatch
```

Got below error:

```
Failed to pull image amazon/aws-for-fluent-bit:2.10.0: rpc error: code 
= Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit Warning Failed 19 minutes kubelet Error: ErrImagePull Normal BackOff 19 minutes kubelet Back-off pulling image amazon/aws-for-fluent-bit:2.10.0 Warning Failed 19 minutes kubelet Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Can anyone please help to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Pull your AWS Fluent Bit image from AWS public ECR instead of dockerhub, change your image url to: `public.ecr.aws/aws-observability/aws-for-fluent-bit:stable`